# basic nestled loop calculate prime numbers between 1 - 239, inclusive

Tags: c++, loops

I am working on a program in which I must print out the number of primes, including 1 and 239, from 1 - 239 ( I know one and or two may not be prime numbers, but we will consider them as such for this program) It must be a pretty simple program because we have only gone over some basics. So far my code is as such, which seems like decent logical flow to me, but doesnt produce output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x;
int n = 1;
int y = 1;
int i = 0;

while (n<=239)
    {x = n % y;
    if (x = 0)
        i++;
    if (y < n)
    y++;
    n++;
    while (i == 2)
        cout << n;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The way I want this to work is to take n, as long as n is 239 or less, and preform modulus division with every number from 1 leading up to n. Every time a number y goes evenly into n, a counter will be increased by 1. if the counter is equal to 2, then the number is prime and we print it to the screen. Any help would be so greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I will look into it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::cout << std::to_string(2) << std::endl;
for (unsigned int i = 3; i<240; i += 2) {
    unsigned int j = 3;
    int sq = sqrt(i);
    for (; j <= sq; j += 2) if (!(i%j)) break;
    if (j>sq) std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
}
```

first of all, the prime definition: A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

so you can skip all the even numbers (and hence ... i+=2).
Moreover no point to try to divide for a number greater than sqrt(i), because then it will have a divisor less than sqrt(i) and the code finds that and move to the next number. 
Considering only odd numbers, means that we can skip even numbers as divisors (hence ... j+=2).

In your code there are clearly beginner errors, like (x = 0) instead of x==0. but also the logic doesn't convince. I agree with @NathanOliver, you need to learn to use a debugger to find all the errors. For the rest, good luck with the studies.

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking the time to walk me through this problem. I am just starting my first semester of programming via online classes at a community college. The teacher is retired and does this on the side, and he seems to not care very much about teaching us anything. He provides no supplementary information, only assigning a program every week, so my only way to learn from that class is to read the chapters and look elsewhere on my own. No complaints though, as I imagine much of programming will require me to self teach. Your code is beautiful, and I now have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

lets start with common errors:

first you want to take input from user using cin

```
cin>>n;  // write it before starting your while loop
```

then,

```
if (x = 0)
```

should be:

```
if (x == 0)
```

change your second while loop to:

```
while (i == 2){
        cout << n;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing these out to me. I was in a hurry typing this just before work, and completely missed these mistakes.